# Replace part of img src

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I need to be able to change a small part of the img src. When an img is uploaded via a free CMS service the path to save the imgs is in a file called www.domain.com so the code then shows the image as `<img src="http://www.domain.com/images/image1.jpg` but the images are actually saved on a cookie free subdomain named 'static'.
So I need something to change the www to static onload.

Please help I have tried several PHP and jQuery scripts, none have worked and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: explain better and shows us some code.. just with the codes we can help.

Comment: I am using a cookie free subdomain to host images and other static files but when imgs are uploaded via CMS the folder they are hosted in is named www. and not static. so the code that is placed on the page shows the src as http://www. and not http://static.
I need something that can change the www. withe static.
I have tried seveal variations of code like this in both PHP and jQuery

`$('img').each(function() {
     $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('src').replace("http://www.domain.com", "http://static.domain.com"));
});`

Comment: Are you trying to get the image from a cookie and echo it into the <img> tag element?

Comment: _"via a free CMS"_. What CMS? _" I have tried several PHP and jQuery scripts"_. What scripts? It's impossible for us to help you if we have no idea what we're dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

You need some way to identify the image from which to extract `src` (does it have an `id`?), but then you can simply do a string replace:

```
myImg.src = myImg.src.replace('domain', 'static.domain');
```

Comment: there are no IDs or classes on the images but there is on the parent Divs. but there are several ID's for the parent Divs

Comment: Ok I'm not sure if I'm heading in the right direction, but after failing to explain what I am trying to do, I have gone away and done some more research and I think what I need to use is PHP DOM Parser.

What I need to do is -
Load the include file where the slide show is
Find every img tag in said file
Break it down to get the file names and extensions
Set the src attribute with new path and the file name & extension
Overwrite old include file with the new file

I have got this so far but have never used this before so am a bit lost.

Comment: `$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('../includes/slides.php');
 foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
  $img->getAttribute('src');
  
  
  $img->setAttribute('src', 'http://static.domain.com/images/ + $filename');
  $doc->saveHTMLFile('../includes/slides.php');
 exit;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This will change the first occurrence of 'www' in each image URL to 'static':

```
var images=document.querySelectorAll('img');
[].forEach.call(images,function(img){
    img.src=img.src.replace('www','static');
});
```

You can make the selector more specific than 'img' to grab exactly the elements you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: It is for every img that is uploaded to the site via CMS. Some of the scripts I have tried, try to replace all of src including the file. This I don't want as the files are named weirdly through the CMS. I simply just want to replace any www's with static.

Comment: This code will replace only the 'www' part. If you want to target specifically images that were uploaded, you'll need some way of telling them apart, either by CSS selector or by a difference in the URLs.

Comment: I just tried that code but didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Pezmo Works on this page. If you provide some examples of what the HTML is like now and what you want it to be, then I can tweak the code. That said, it's probably better to handle this on the server side. If you do it with JavaScript, users will probably see a flash of broken images right as the page loads.

Comment: I agree, I searched Google and on here and all I could find were jQuery scripts that used onClick or if a user did something. PHP would be better as it is server side but im not that experienced with regex etc. I need it to change the src as mentioned before from www. to static. The file does not need to be moved as it is in the same folder as all the other images but the CMS uses www. instead of static. And there is no way of changing it on upload to say to upload to www.domain.com/images but have the path as static.domain.com (CNAME not A). If the src shows static.domain.com/images/image.jpg